# Reading wall data for app

Tags: php, facebook

How do I write code in PHP that allows me to parse (store in an array), all posts showing up on the facebook wall.

The code below fetches wall data only before the 'show older posts' sign on the wall. I want all the data there in an array.

```
$wall = idx($facebook->api('/me/feed'), 'data', array());
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get facebook wall data is

```
    $response=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".id."/feed&access_token=".$facebook_access_token);
$response_array=json_decode($response,true);
```

But you cannot get all posts from above request. you have to pass pagination parameters like since,limit,until etc.

Please refer Facebook documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/